# Loading multiple spinners from mysql database in android

Tags: android, mysql, spinner

In my android application Iam having 6 spinners and I need to load them with the data which is present in mysql database according to category wise.And Iam using json to retrieve the data and sent back to the android but here Iam not getting how to assign the data to spinners.Please help me to solve this.

```
public void getItems(int l)
{
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+l, 5000).show();
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams autofill_params = new RequestParams();
    autofill_params.put("sending_category_id_JSON",autofill_composeJSONfromSQLite(l));
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sending JSON ==> "+autofill_params,5000).show();
    client.post("http://www.XXXX.com/mobile_cycle/spares_auto_fill.php", autofill_params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()

        {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response)

        {       
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Responce is ==>"+response, 5000).show();
            //spinner_updater();
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            try 
            {
                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Length ==> "+arr.length(), 5000).show();
                //public String temp_array[];
                final String[] temp_array = new String[5];
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) 
                {
                    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);
                    //auto_first_name = obj.get("name").toString();
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Length ==> "+arr.length(), 5000).show();
                    String item_name = obj.get("name").toString();
                    temp_array[i] = item_name;
                    //spinner_updater(item_name);
                }

                spinner_updater(temp_array);

            }
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //fillData(autofill_network_flag);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,String content)

        {

            if (statusCode == 404) 

            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 

            else if (statusCode == 500) 

            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 

            else 

            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet]",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    });
    }

public void spinner_updater(String[] item_name)

{

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inside Updater Item Length ==> "+item_name.length, 5000).show();

    for(int length = 0; length < item_name.length; length++)

    {
        String empty_temp = " ";

        String temp_item = item_name[length];

        if(temp_item.equals(empty_temp))

        {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item ==> "+item_name[length], 5000).show();
        }

        else

        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item ==> "+item_name[length], 5000).show();
        }
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adp2 = new ArrayAdapter<String> 
    (this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, str1);
    sp2.setAdapter(adp2);

}
```

Comment: This link is a good example of populating spinner from mysql database.
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/12/android-populating-spinner-data-from-mysql-database/

Comment: where are you inserting data in db

Comment: according to my situation there are five category_id in my database so that according to them i should load 5 spinners with the data.I have retrieved the data but I should store them now in an arrays and assign that array to a spinner adapter.

Answer (score 0):

first create list as many as spinner

```
         List<String> list1, list2, list;

        list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        list3 = new ArrayList<String>();


    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1 );
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2 );
    spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3 );
```

now add data to each list from database or from json

```
                SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getReadableDatabase();

                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from frnds", null);
            adding first row items in first list    
for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor
                        .moveToNext()) {
                    // do what you need with the cursor here
                 list1.add(cursor.getString(1));
                    }
```

adding second row items in second list

```
 for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor
                            .moveToNext()) {
                        // do what you need with the cursor here
                     list2.add(cursor.getString(2));
                        }
```

adding third row items in third list

```
for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor
                        .moveToNext()) {
                    // do what you need with the cursor here
                 list3.add(cursor.getString(3));
                    }
                cursor.close();
```

setting list to spinner

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> spinner1Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                                list1);
                        spinner1Adapter
                                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        spinner1.setAdapter(spinner1Adapter);

        ArrayAdapter<String> spinner2Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                                list2);
                        spinner2Adapter
                                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        spinner2.setAdapter(spinner2Adapter);

        ArrayAdapter<String> spinner3Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                                list3);
                        spinner3Adapter
                                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


                spinner3.setAdapter(spinner3Adapter);
```

Comment: hey @raj tq for ur reply but i asked how to retrieve them from mysql database.

Comment: you need to create for loop as defined in code above